# Install BTRFS Rootfs inside LVM Volume inside MDADM RAID

Tags: lvm, mdadm, btrfs

is it a good idea in terms of performance and stability? I have 4 disks whit the same size where i want to install the rootfs(opensuse) using btrfs, but i need  swap and virtualmachine storage.. Because of that i need to use a filesystem that supports raw, and i thought lvm is the best choice..

At this point, is it possible to combine lvm and btrfs?

Next point, is it a good idea to combine btrfs raid and lvm raid or is it better to use a mdadm raid?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to use MD > LVM > BTRFS as a filesystem. However, don't mix BTRFS RAID and linux MD RAID on the same system. There's no technical reason why you shouldn't, but it would be very disorganized. I would hope that such a solution would be only for your personal machine and not for anyone else to look at in the future.

Keep a consistent storage stack and try not to mix a bunch of different RAID mechanisms. If you want to use BTRFS RAID, use that. Otherwise, use Linux MD > LVM, or just LVM.

Comment: As an aside, it IS possible to use a file for swap and to put the Grub on any btrfs raid level directly (despite what that awful rhel / centos installer demands). This is certainly a far more simple and centrally managed storage stack, but btrfs virtualization performance isn't awesome (though it's MUCH better than it used to be, especially with the "nodatacow" option). I've used it for lab environments with tens of VMs per node with almost no visible issue, but I'm too picky about performance to put it in prod.